# php multidimensional array count duplicate values and add corresponding values

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, mapping

I have a php array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location] => Kansas
            [kit] => Moving Kit
            [quantity] => 1
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [location] => Louisiana
        [kit] => Anchored4Life DVD Kit
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [location] => Louisiana
        [kit] => Anchored4Life DVD Kit
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [location] => Louisiana
        [kit] => Anchored4Life DVD Kit
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [location] => Pennsylvania
        [kit] => Anchored4Life DVD Kit
        [quantity] => 5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [location] => Pennsylvania
        [kit] => Welcome Kit
        [quantity] => 1
    )

)
```

And I want to sort it so that I receive the data according to location and and kits and their quantity and quantity  if the kits are slimier.

ON the  `Louisiana Anchored4Life DVD Kit` is repeated so I would like to know how many kits orders in Every state like `Louisiana Anchored4Life DVD Kit` quantity 3.

I have tried `array_count_values()` but that only counts according to strings and I need it for the multiple kits and kits are not predefined.

Comment: so what you want finally? your question is unclear. please share expected outcome properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to hold of on posting but then I see the other answers.

You say group on location so I assume this is what you need:
I group on location in an associative array and then subarray the different kits, if the kit is already added I sum the quantity.

```
foreach($arr as $sub){
    if(!isset($res[$sub['location']])){
        $res[$sub['location']][$sub['kit']] = $sub;
    }elseif(!isset($res[$sub['location']][$sub['kit']])){
        $res[$sub['location']][$sub['kit']] = $sub;
    }else{
        $res[$sub['location']][$sub['kit']]['quantity'] += $sub['quantity'];
    }
}

var_dump($res);
```

This returns:

```
array(3) {
  ["Kansas"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Moving Kit"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["location"]=>
      string(6) "Kansas"
      ["kit"]=>
      string(10) "Moving Kit"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
  ["Louisiana"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Anchored4Life DVD Kit"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["location"]=>
      string(9) "Louisiana"
      ["kit"]=>
      string(21) "Anchored4Life DVD Kit"
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(3)
    }
  }
  ["Pennsylvania"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Anchored4Life DVD Kit"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["location"]=>
      string(12) "Pennsylvania"
      ["kit"]=>
      string(21) "Anchored4Life DVD Kit"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(1) "5"
    }
    ["Welcome Kit"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["location"]=>
      string(12) "Pennsylvania"
      ["kit"]=>
      string(11) "Welcome Kit"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/DgPKp

Comment: Thanks @Andreas that is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all. But, I think you want to count orders grouped by products. I suggest you to create a very simple helper like :

```
    public function getCount($items, $kitName) : int
    {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item['kit'] === $kitName) {
                $count ++;
            }
        }

        return $count;
    }
```

This helper get how many orders correspond to a given kit